# Reject_if not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, nested-forms

I have some troubles with `:reject_if`. I don't know why the following code doesn't work.

**View - _form.html.erb:**

```
<%= f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
  <div class="nested-field">
    <%= builder.label :id, "Question" %><br />
    <%= builder.collection_select(:id, Question.all(:order => 'question'), :id, :question, { :prompt => 'Select Question' } ) %>
  </div>
  <div class="nested-field">
    <%= builder.label :test1 %><br />
    <%= builder.text_field :test1 %>
  </div>
  <div class="nested-field">
    <%= builder.label :test2 %><br />
    <%= builder.text_field :test2 %>
  </div>
  <div class="nested-field">
    <%= builder.label :description %><br />
    <%= builder.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <br /><br /><br />
  <hr />
<% end %>
```

**Model - questionary.rb:**

```
has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:id].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
:reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:id].blank? }
```

try

```
:reject_if => lambda { |a| a['id'].blank? }
```

(note the string 'id') and to follow the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) exactly, use proc

```
:reject_if => proc { |a| a['id'].blank? }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the [API for accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), and found there that the documentation states:

> :reject_if
>   Allows you to specify a Proc or a Symbol pointing to a method that checks whether a record should be built for a certain attribute hash.

Have you tried to replace the lambda with proc? The syntax here seems to be special, so the lambda may be just ignored.